# Best practice to show Apollo Client Query loading outside of Query Component?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I want to show loading indicator outside of my query component.

Right now I'm using redux and when I start loading data from api, I set redux state attribute which I then use to show loader component.

How to achieve same thing with Apollo Client Query/Mutations?
Every example shows loading prop inside Query but how to show loader outside of this Query?

Lets say I have something like this:

```
<Header><Loader/></Header>
<Content><Query><List /></Query></Content>
```

But I do not want to wrap everything with Query and do something like this:

```
<Query>
<Header><Loader/></Header>
<Content><List ></Content>
</Query>
```

Is it even possible ?
Should i mutate `@client` cache inside Query when loading ?

Edit: I want to replace redux with apollo-link-state, so solution should not use redux.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [react-apollo-hooks](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks), it make Apollo usage much more easy and fun.

Have a look at sample code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-apollo-hooks';
import get from 'lodash.get';
import SUBSCRIPTIONS_QUERY from './Subscriptions.graphql';
import s from './SubscriptionTable.scss';

const SubscriptionsTable = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(SUBSCRIPTIONS_QUERY);

  if (loading) return "Loading...";
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <div className={s.SubscriptionTable}>
      <div className={s.SubscriptionTable__Header}>Email</div>
      {get(data, 'subscriptions', []).map(subscription => (
        <div key={get(subscription, 'id')} className={s.SubscriptionTable__Row}>
          {get(subscription, 'email')}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: While that looks interesting, i don't think it will solve my question. 

If i do it like this:


const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(SUBSCRIPTIONS_QUERY);
const { data: data1, loading: loading1, error:error1 } = useQuery(SUBSCRIPTIONS_QUERY);

If i then somehow refetch first one, then second one will probably not show loading?

Comment: It is direction, not the solution

Comment: @Lauri Apollo caches based on queries and variables. So the data1 set will never hit the network. You'd need to deploy a refetch or make it a useLazyQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's no reason to put your loading state in Redux, but if you really want to for some reason you should set your redux state to `loading: true` when the component mounts, and set your redux state to `loading: false` when loading is no longer true in the component. Here's what I mean:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useQuery,
  useEffect
} from 'react-apollo-hooks';
import get from 'lodash.get';
import SUBSCRIPTIONS_QUERY from './Subscriptions.graphql';
import s from './SubscriptionTable.scss';

const SubscriptionsTable = () => {
  const {
    data,
    loading,
    error
  } = useQuery(SUBSCRIPTIONS_QUERY);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set loading: true in redux state 
    // as soon as component mounts
    // via action/reducer pattern
  }, [])

  if (loading) {
    return "Loading..."
  } else {
    // set loading: false in redux state 
    // when query no longer loading
    // via action/reducer pattern
  }

  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (<div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>);
};
```